# Pandas how to filter for multiple substrings in series

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I would like to check if pandas dataframe column `id` contains the following substrings `'.F1', '.N1', '.FW', '.SP'`.

I am currently using the following codes:

```
searchfor = ['.F1', '.N1', '.FW', '.SP']
mask = (df["id"].str.contains('|'.join(searchfor)))
```

The `id` column looks like such:

```
                   ID
0  F611B4E369F1D293B5
1  10302389527F190F1A
```

I am actually looking to see if the `id` column contains the four substrings starting with a `.`. For some reasons, `F1` will be filtered out. In the current example, it does not have `.F1`. I would really appreciate if someone would let me know how to solve this particular issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: `.` matches anything. So the expression `.F1` would be anything followed by `F1`. Both strings have this pattern. `9F1` in index 0 and `7F1` and `0F1` in index 1. It's also unclear how you're _using_ the mask since this should match both of the shown ids.

Comment: You can escape with `'\.F1'` or with `re.escape()`

Comment: `df["ID"].str.contains('\\'+'|\\'.join(searchfor))`

Comment: @AndrejKesely thank you so much for the suggestion. Just to confirm it will be escape with "\.F1" in the first row right?

Comment: @SkipperLin Try this `searchfor = ['\.F1', '\.N1', '\.FW', '\.SP']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`re.escape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) to escape the regex meta-characters in the following way such that you don't need to escape every string in the word list `searchfor` *(no need to change the definition of `searchfor`)*:

```
import re

searchfor = ['.F1', '.N1', '.FW', '.SP']            # no need to escape each string

pattern = '|'.join(map(re.escape, searchfor))       # use re.escape() with map()

mask = (df["id"].str.contains(pattern))
```

[`re.escape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) will escape each string for you:

```
print(pattern)

'\\.F1|\\.N1|\\.FW|\\.SP'
```